# what is filtering invalid utf8 from my PHP website?

Tags: php, utf-8, utf, mbstring

My website is fully converted to use utf-8, (mysql, http headers, PHP mb_string etc).

Im doing some penetration testing and trying to POST invalid utf to one of the scripts (using BurpSuite).

But when I post the invalid utf, an just hex-dump the $_POST var, I see that the invalid utf sequence has already been sanitised before I try to validate it using mb_detect_encoding.

This sounds like good news for me, but I want to know which layer is transforming the POST data?

Is it a side-effect of the Content-Type HTTP Header, maybe my webserver is doing it (lighttpd). Or is it PHP itself doing it, when populating $_POST?

I expected to see the invalid utf hexdumped, leaving me to sanitise it myself.

Comment: More information would help, are you on a framework? which PHP version are you using? can we see a sample of your code etc

Comment: Can we see what you posted and what you got back?

Comment: No, no framework. Just vanilla PHP and a raw HTTP request from burpsuite, and then the PHP script simply hex-dumps a $_POST["formvalue"]. There's no preprocessing of $_REQUEST/$_POST or any user input in my code prior to hexdumping it  -- Sorting out an example now...

Comment: Simple PHP example, and request/response dumps at http://carpii.homeip.net/utf_test.txt -- initial test is for a 3 byte sequence (a Euro character), where the 3rd byte has been mangled to be invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP itself does not filter the POST data, it just handles it as binary data which is always "valid" (it's just data, nothing to validate).

I would therefore suspect that there is some module with your webserver that is changing the data or there's some PHP extension that is filtering the data.

Check if you've got a web-firewall installed with your webserver and the list of extensions you're loading with PHP and if there is something input filtering related.

Comment: no framework, no web firewall, apparently lighttpd does not try to filter invalid utf8 either. Im pretty baffled. No strange extensions, although I am working through those. Do you know of any mbstring config settings which could be causing it?

Comment: mbstring has default encoding, sure. And you might have those registered on input and/or output. See [the **PHP Settings** and **String** sections in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6987929/367456#6989048). I listed some ini settings that play a role. To really look into the data you process, I often find a [hex dump of PHP strings](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1057572/367456) handy.

Comment: Thanks, I eventually found that it was being caused by php.ini mbstring setting... mbstring.http_input = auto.     When set to auto, it appears to do silent conversion of charset which was giving the impression the invalid utf was being properly sanitisied. I think more likely though, the conversion was failing and returning blank string