# UTF-8 problems in php: var_export() returns \0 null characters, and ucfirst(), strtoupper(), etc. behave strangely

Tags: php, utf-8, localization, joyent

We are dealing with a strange bug in a Joyent Solaris server that never happened before (doesn't happen in localhost or two other Solaris servers with identical php configuration). Actually, I'm not sure if we have to look at php or solaris, and if it is a software or hardware problem...

I just want to post this in case somebody can point us in the right direction.

So, the problem seems to be in `var_export()`when dealing with strange characters.
Executing this in the CLI, we get the expected result in our localhost machines and in two of the servers, but not in the 3rd one. All of them are configured to work with `utf-8`.

```
$ php -r "echo var_export('ñu', true);"
```

Gives this in older servers and localhost **(expected)**:

```
'ñu'
```

But in the server we are having problems with (**PHP Version => 5.3.6**), it adds `\0` null characters whenever it encounters an "uncommon" character: è, á, ç, ... you name it.

```
'' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . 'u'
```

Any idea on where should be looking at? Thanks in advance.

---

**More info:**

- `PHP version 5.3.6`.
- `setlocale()` is not solving anything.
- `default_charset` is `UTF-8` in `php.ini`.
- `mbstring.internal_encoding` is set to `UTF-8` in `php.ini`.
- `mbstring.func_overload = 0`.
- this happens in both CLI (example) and web application (php-fpm + nginx).
- `iconv` encoding is also `UTF-8`
- all files `utf-8` encoded.

`system('locale')` returns:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

---

**Some of the tests done so far (CLI):**

Normal behaviour:

```
$ php -r "echo bin2hex('ñu');" => 'c3b175'
$ php -r "echo mb_strtoupper('ñu');" => 'ÑU'
$ php -r "echo serialize(\"\\xC3\\xB1\");" => 's:2:"ñ";'
$ php -r "echo bin2hex(addcslashes(b\"\\xC3\\xB1\", \"'\\\\\"));" => 'c3b1'
$ php -r "echo ucfirst('iñu');" => 'Iñu'
```

Not normal:

```
$ php -r "echo strtoupper('ñu');" => 'U' 
$ php -r "echo ucfirst('ñu');" => '?u' 
$ php -r "echo ucfirst(b\"\\xC3\\xB1u\");" => '?u' 
$ php -r "echo bin2hex(ucfirst('ñu'));" => '00b175'
$ php -r "echo bin2hex(var_export('ñ', 1));" => '2727202e20225c3022202e202727202e20225c3022202e202727'
$ php -r "echo bin2hex(var_export(b\"\\xC3\\xB1\", 1));" => '2727202e20225c3022202e202727202e20225c3022202e202727'
```

So the problem seems to be in `var_export()` and ["string functions that use the current locale but operate byte-by-byte" <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.details) (view @hakre's answer).

Comment: I'd start by checking the version of software running on each server. Specifically php. A function in one version assumes UTF-8 while the same function in a different version assumes ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Also try comparing the output of `locale(1)` and/or checking the environment variables that start with `LC`.

Comment: Does this only happen on the CLI? That may be some special case of how Solaris' terminal handles Unicode. Or does this happen as well when running from source code files which guaranteed do not contain `NUL` bytes?

Comment: Check two things, one the php.ini that gets executed at CLI (might differ from the one over webserver), setting there the default_charset to "utf-8". Secondly check /etc/locale.gen if you even have an en_US.UTF-8 on that one server.

Comment: @deceze this happens in both CLI (example) and web application (php-fpm + nginx).

Comment: @Christian `php.ini`'s default_charset is `UTF-8`.

Comment: Interspersing characters with NULs means that you're probably looking at UTF-16.

Comment: @DavidBélanger default iconv encoding in the server now is `ISO-8859-1`. I changed it to `UTF-8` some days ago in `php.ini` but the problem remained, so I reverted it to the original configuration...

Comment: @DavidBélanger double checked :) iconv encoded as `UTF-8` doesn't change a thing, both `var_export()` and `ucfirst()` don't work.

Comment: If it's available on your server, try detecting the actual encoding with `mb_detect_encoding()`

Comment: @Niko mbstring extension is available in `php.ini`, and `mbstring.internal_encoding` is set to `UTF-8`. `mb_detect_encoding('ñu')` returns `UTF-8`.

Comment: @eillarra And how about `mb_detect_encoding(ucfirst('ñu'))`?

Comment: @Niko `mb_detect_encoding(ucfirst('ñu'))` returns `false`.

Comment: `mb_detect_encoding` is broken by design. Don't rely on that function, it's outcome does not say much. Handle with care.

Comment: I think your best bet, is to check if the string has valid caracters... yesterday I was trying to htmlentities a string and the result was NULL but my var had some char from word (that what I found)... so try to encodo something else manually.

Comment: @DavidBélanger thanks for the comment, but string is 'clean', and as you can see the problem happens both in CLI and server (all tests included are in CLI).

Comment: @eillarra Okay, it's very weird... I try to think why but it's hard when I am not in the hood...

Comment: I'm sure this is related to Solaris and the system C libraries that are used by PHP. I'd say that the compiled packages have been messed by the hoster, otherwise `strtoupper` must be working. Get proper binaries.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you verify the PHP binary you've got problems with. Check the compiler flags and the libraries it makes use of.

Normally PHP internally uses binary strings, which means that functions like `ucfirst` work byte-to-byte and only support what your locale support (if and like configured). See [*Details of the String Type*<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.details).

```
$ php -r "echo ucfirst('ñu');"
```

returns

```
?u
```

This makes sense, `ñ` is

```
LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH TILDE (U+00F1)    UTF8: \xC3\xB1
```

You have some locale configured that makes PHP change `\xC3` into something else, breaking the UTF-8 byte-sequence and making your shell display the [� replacement character<sup>*Wikipedia*</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)).

I suggest if you really want to analyze the issues, you should start with [hexdumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057572/how-can-i-get-a-hex-dump-of-a-string-in-php) next to how things get displayed in shell and elsewhere.
Know that you can explicitly define binrary strings `b"string"` (that's forward compatibility, mabye you've got enabled some compile flag and you're on unicode experimental?), and also you can write strings literally, here hex-way for UTF-8:

```
 $ php -r "echo ucfirst(b\"\\xC3\\xB1u\");"
```

And there are a lot more settings that can play a role, I started to list some points in [an answer to *Preparing PHP application to use with UTF-8*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6989048/367456).

---

Example of a multibyte `ucfirst` variant:

```
/**
 * multibyte ucfirst
 *
 * @param string $str
 * @param string|null $encoding (optional)
 * @return string
 */
function mb_ucfirst($str, $encoding = NULL)
{
    $first = mb_substr($str, 0, 1, $encoding);
    $rest = mb_substr($str, 1, strlen($str), $encoding);
    return mb_strtoupper($first, $encoding) . $rest;
}
```

See [`mb_strtoupper`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/mb_strtoupper) and as well [`mb_convert_case`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/mb_convert_case).

Comment: I've made the 'hexadecimal test': all the servers, including the 'bad guy', return `c3b175` when executing `$ php -r "echo bin2hex('ñu');"`. Not sure how I should interpret this...

Comment: And `$ php -r "echo ucfirst(b\"\\xC3\\xB1u\");"` returns `?u`.

Comment: and what does `bin2hex(ucfirst('ñu'));` give? (your report show that for both cases, PHP uses the UTF-8 sequences inside the strings, so that is the same across those systems).

Comment: `bin2hex(ucfirst('ñu'));` returns `00b175`.

Comment: On the system that's broken I guess. You locale is changing `0xC3` to `0x00`. What does it give on a system that works? And keep in mind you *need* to use `mb_ucfirst('ñu', 'UTF-8')` (multibyte replacement for `ucfirst`) anyway, because it's a multibyte charset you use (UTF-8).

Comment: Yes, `00b175` is in the 'broken' server. The others just return `c3b175`. Can't use `mb_ucfirst()`, are you sure that function exists? Is not here... http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php

Comment: That `mb_ucfirst` was virtual, I'll add one to the answer for an example.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean: I added a `mb_strtoupper()` test to the question. Results differ in the 'broken' server.

Comment: @eillarra: Can you please give the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: `SunOS 7aaefcc.local 5.11 joyent_20120126T071347Z i86pc i386 i86pc Solaris`. As I say in the question is a Joyent machine, SmartOS they call it (based in Solaris), w/ PHP 5.3.6

Comment: Well, as this is related to `strtoupper` even, I suspect it's related to the underlying c libs when PHP has been compiled. You should check with Joynet support and ask them for providing a properly configured/compiled binary. Also I suggest you get a PHP version that's a more current PHP 5.3 one, like PHP 5.3.10.

Answer (score 0):

try force utf-8 in php:

```
<? ini_set( 'default_charset', 'UTF-8' ); ?>
```

in very top (first line of code) of your any page/template. It helps me with my special characters mostly. Not sure that it can help you too, try it.

Comment: default_charset is `UTF-8` in `php.ini`. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Probably all your servers are in good state . In one of the comments you said that you have only issue with ucfirst() and var_export(). Depending on these responses you might be looking at this [SOQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517947/ucfirst-function-for-multibyte-character-encodings). Most of the php string function will not work properly when working with multibyte strings. That is why php has [separate set of functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) to deal with them.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451144/php-multi-byte-str-replace) might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I normally use `utf8_encode('ñu')` for all the french characters

Comment: Thanks Vinay, but it seems to be an underlying C problem, maybe a compilation problem. Still trying to find it out, but PHP doesn't seem to be the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

phpunit tests for this are being added to https://gist.github.com/68f5781a83a8986b9d30 - can we build up a better unit test suite so that we can figure out what the expected output should be?