# BSON encoding with binary data

Tags: php, mongodb, binary, bson

I m looking for a way to encode in BSON some binary data. as BSON stands for binary json , I tought it was simple.

However when I want to pack some binary data using bson_encode (from mongoDB package PHP)

I get an exception

```
$data = AD_Dbase::GetSingleRowResult("SELECT ghost_data FROM ghosts WHERE id=1"); // binary data(blob in mysql)

echo bson_encode(array(1,"this is a test",$data));
```

Exception :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoException' with message 'non-utf8 string: 3' in test.php:7 Stack trace: #0 test.php(7): bson_encode(Array) #1 {main} thrown in test.php on line 7
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Why not use some of the other functionality built into the MongoDB driver?  From the documentation: "This function is very beta and entirely useless for 99% of users. It is only useful if you're doing something weird, such as writing your own driver on top of the PHP driver."  http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongobindata.php

Comment: Despite of the weird solution to something I don't understand, the problem is you're not using UTF8 strings, if you don't prepare php to use UTF8 in this enconding I think it won't work. It's a guess bc I'm not sure how bson encoding works in php, I've never needed anything similar :) Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987929/preparing-php-application-to-use-with-utf-8

Comment: $data  is not a string at all, it binary serialized list of float (3 float for a vector x,y,z + a float for time) and the first in in the BLOB is the size of the structure.

Comment: but problem fixed if I use Stennie suggestion above (MongoBinData)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BSON spec supports a number of different [field types](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification).

The `bson_encode` function you are calling is used to serialise data into a BSON document, which must be in UTF-8 format. This is a lower-level function intended for use in drivers.

If you want to store or retrieve binary data in a field, you should instead use the [MongoBinData class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongobindata.php).

Comment: Thanks Stennie, using new MongoBinData($data) solved the problem.

Comment: please notice that you may have to change the default type of MongoBinData as the PHP lib use the old binary format as default.